# CSS Skew/Shadow/Hover-over bug in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I've an issue whereby if you are to hover upon an `<li>` element that has been skewed (from a CSS3 transform) and a shadow applied to it, the shadow it generates will then be rendered incorrectly. It's probably better to see the issue first-hand here - http://jsfiddle.net/mabbage/BLD5Z/1/

It seems this issue is confined to web-kit browsers (Chrome and Safari). Does anyone know of a workaround to this?

One thing I have discovered when playing around with it is if you remove the shadow of the nav object, then this whole issue disappears (however, I'd like a shadow behind the whole list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could find was to use PNG images to style the `<li>` elements and the shadow behind it. I'm putting this problem down as a CSS3 bug in webkit browsers.